# How does ConcurrentHashMap work when read and write request come for the same segment?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to understand how locks work in ConcurrentHashMap. My understanding is that in ConcurrentHashMap there are segments and a write requests acquires a lock on a particular segment while there can be simultaneous reads on other segments. But say,

1. A read request comes in for segment 10, and a write request comes in for the same segment 10. While a request is reading, a write request tries to modify it. How does the write request know it has to wait until a read is finished? Are there two separate locks one for read and one write lock in ConcurrentHashMap or just one lock? Does write have to acquire a read lock too for writing and that's the reason why write waits? If there is only one lock how does simultaneous read work?
2. Two requests 1 and 2 come in for the same segment 2. Request 1 acquires the lock on segment 1, does the request have to wait until 2 has finished reading?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the implementation? https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand ConcurrentHashMap, is by understanding synchronization in java in reviewing the source code.
From the Source code
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java

> Insertion (via +[]=+ or its variants) of the first node in an empty
> bin is performed by just CASing it to the bin. This is by far the most
> common case for put operations under most key/hash distributions.
> Other update operations (insert, delete, and replace) require locks.
> We do not want to waste the space required to associate a distinct
> lock object with each bin, so instead use the first node of a bin list
> itself as a lock. Blocking support for these locks relies
> +`Util::CheapLockable`. However, we also need a try_lock construction, so we overlay these by using bits of the Node hash field for lock
> control (see above), and so normally use builtin monitors only for
> blocking and signalling using `cheap_wait/cheap_broadcast`
> constructions. See +Node#try_await_lock+. Locking support for these
> locks relies on builtin "synchronized" monitors. which mean

Which basically means every Insert/Update/Delete operation on ConcurrentHashMap will blocked until the operation is finished

for read value there is no blocking

```
public V get(Object key) {

        Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> e, p; int n, eh; K ek;

        int h = spread(key.hashCode());

        if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&

            (e = tabAt(tab, (n - 1) & h)) != null) {

            if ((eh = e.hash) == h) {

                if ((ek = e.key) == key || (ek != null && key.equals(ek)))

                    return e.val;

            }

            else if (eh < 0)

                return (p = e.find(h, key)) != null ? p.val : null;

            while ((e = e.next) != null) {

                if (e.hash == h &&

                    ((ek = e.key) == key || (ek != null && key.equals(ek))))

                    return e.val;

            }

        }

        return null;
    }
```